# How to get check box value of a attribute

Tags: jquery

i want to get value of attribute value of checkboxes.
my code is giving me **undefined**

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').each(function () {
            var row = $(this);

            if ( row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') ) {
                alert( $(this).attr("b_partner_id") );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is referring to the `tr` element in the `if` block, since your `b_partner_id` attribute is not present in the `tr` element you are getting `undefined`.

Instead you need to get the attribute value using the `checkbox` reference

```
$('#mytable').find('tr').each(function () {
    var row = $(this),
        $check = row.find('input[type="checkbox"]');

    if ($check.is(':checked')) {
        alert($check.attr("b_partner_id"));
    }
});
```